# CSS Width Animation Direction

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, css-animations

I am trying to animate the width of a span element.

This is how my HTML + CSS + jQuery looks like:

```css
.tt {
 position: absolute;
 width: 55px;
 height: 3px;
 background-color: #999997;
 top: 0;
 right: 10px;
 opacity: 0; 
}

.tt-expand {
 width: 55px;
 opacity: 1; 
 animation: 1s ease tt-expand;  
}

@keyframes tt-expand {

 0% {
 width: 0;
 }
 100% {
 width: 55px;
 }

}

.relative {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px 28px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

setTimeout(function(){
 $( '.tt' ).addClass( 'tt-expand' );
}, 1000 );

});
</script>

<div class="relative">
  <h2>Heading</h2>
  <span class="tt"></span>
</div>
```

**The problem:**

The line animates from **right to left.**

**The preferred outcome:**

Ideally, the line should animate from **left to right**

[image: Animation Illustration]

**Question**

How can I get the width of my SPAN element to animate from left to right?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use `right` to position an element, its `width` grows from right, so you need to position it at left, here done using [CSS Calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/calc), `left: calc(100% - 10px - 55px);`

```css
.tt {
  position: absolute;
  width: 55px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #999997;
  top: 0;
  left: calc(100% - 10px - 55px);
  opacity: 0;
}

.tt-expand {
  width: 55px;
  opacity: 1;
  animation: tt-expand 1s ease;
}

@keyframes tt-expand {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  100% {
    width: 55px;
  }
}

.relative {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px 28px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    setTimeout(function() {
      $('.tt').addClass('tt-expand');
    }, 1000);

  });
</script>

<div class="relative">
  <h2>Heading</h2>
  <span class="tt"></span>
</div>
```

---

If one for some reason can't use CSS Calc, you can do like this, where you animate both the width and right values

```css
.tt {
  position: absolute;
  width: 55px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #999997;
  top: 0;
  right: 10px;
  opacity: 0;
}

.tt-expand {
  width: 55px;
  opacity: 1;
  animation: tt-expand 1s ease;
}

@keyframes tt-expand {
  0% {
    width: 0;
    right: 65px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 55px;
    right: 10px;
  }
}

.relative {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px 28px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    setTimeout(function() {
      $('.tt').addClass('tt-expand');
    }, 1000);

  });
</script>

<div class="relative">
  <h2>Heading</h2>
  <span class="tt"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Fantastic !   Just what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 2):

Assigning `left:50%` to class `.tt-expand` should help, as below, that's because `position` of `parent is relative`, if you have not assigned `position:relative` to `parent` element then this won't work, actually it works but `aligns` or performs that `border animation` from center of page.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
setTimeout(function(){
$('.tt').addClass( 'tt-expand' );
}, 1000 );
});
```

```css
 .tt {
    position: absolute;
    width: 55px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: #999997;
    top: 0;
    right: 10px;
    opacity: 0; 
}
.tt-expand {
    width: 55px;
    opacity: 1; 
    animation: 1s ease tt-expand;
    right:0;
    left:50%;/*Add this*/
}

@keyframes tt-expand {
0% {
   width: 0;
}
100% {
    width: 55px;
}
}
.relative {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px 28px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="relative">
<h2>Heading</h2>
<span class="tt"></span>
</div>
```